# inserting multiple segues into a if else statement in swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, overriding, segue

Right now I have 2 labels lebelText and lebelText2. Only lebelText2 is being segued to the next view controller. I need both lebelText and lebelText2 to be transferred to the next view controller.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let DestViewController : winViewController = segue.destination as! winViewController
    DestViewController.LebelText = emma.text!
}

func updateTimer() {
    counter += 0.1
    labelx.text = String(format: "%.1f", counter)
    if counter < 9.9 && level == 2 {
        if let nextc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "winViewController") as? winViewController {
            nextc.LebelText2 = labelx.text
            self.present(nextc, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So what's your question? You could just add another assignment inside your if statement that says `next.lebeltext = someOtherLabel.text`.

Comment: I wouldn't call this a duplicate of the other question, but rather the second in a series of indecipherable questions about the same general subject.

Comment: Check out my answer to your other question http://stackoverflow.com/a/41539180/5378116